# D3.js how to embed selection into a new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am wondering if there is a native function in D3.js to create new element around (embedding) the selection.
For instance I have a structure like this :

```
<path ...></path>
<path ...></path>
<path ...></path>
<path ...></path>
<path ...></path>
```

And I want to get that :

```
<path ...></path>
<path ...></path>
<g>
    <path ...></path>
</g>
<path ...></path>
<path ...></path>
```

So I just create a new element around my selection.

I Think we can do something like : get the selection, detach it, create the  element and insert the selection into the new element. 
I am sorry if this question has been posted already, I struggle to explain that in English.

Any suggestion appreciate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although in D3 there is no such thing as jQuery's [`.wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/), it is fairly easy to do the DOM manipulations yourself. You need to use two of D3's methods:

1. [`selection.insert(name[, before])`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_insert) to insert the wrapping element at the desired position in the DOM tree. This will return the newly inserted element.
2. [`selection.append()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_append) to append the element to be wrapped to the newly created wrapping element. Note, that there is no need to remove the existing node first before appending it to the wrapping element! A node cannot exists in two points of the DOM tree and, thus, the method [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) which is [used](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/append.js#L6) by D3 internally takes care of moving the node instead of cloning it. In the words of the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#wikiArticle):

   > If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, `appendChild()` moves it from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node).

Chained together you will end up with something like the following:

```js
d3.select("svg")
    .insert("g", "#c")                      // Insert the wrapper before <path id="c">.
    .append(() => d3.select("#b").node());  // Append the wrapped element to it.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="100" height="100">
    <path id="a" d="M1 1"></path>
    <path id="b" d="M1 1"></path>
    <path id="c" d="M1 1"></path>
</svg>
```

This will produce the following result:

```xml
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <path id="a" d="M1 1"></path>
    <g>
        <path id="b" d="M1 1"></path>
    </g>
    <path id="c" d="M1 1"></path>
</svg>
```

---

Alternatively, you could wrap this in a function and extend [`d3.selection`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection):

```js
d3.selection.prototype.wrap = function wrap() { 
  const node = this.node();
  const g = d3.select(node.parentNode).insert("g", () => node);
  g.append(() => node);
  return g;
}

d3.select("#b").wrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```