# How to move some tags inside another tag with d3?

Tags: d3.js

I have svg like this:

```
<svg id="mySvg">
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
</svg>
```

But I would like to group all paths in this svg inside the **g** tag, so it would look like that:

```
<svg id="mySvg">
    <g>
        <path></path>
        <path></path>
        <path></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

How should I do it?

```
d3.select("#mySvg").append("g") // -> and move all paths inside g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove elements with `selection.remove()`. This method will return a selection of the removed elements.

You can also use `selection.append()` to append those elements. However, selection.append only takes a function or a string. If you supply a function it should return a (single) element/node. We can access the element/node of a selection of one element with `selection.node()`

This gives us the pattern:

```js
let svg = d3.select('svg')

let path = svg.selectAll('path').remove();

svg.append('g').append(()=>path.node());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <path d="M 30 30 C 60 30 50 50 80 50" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none"></path>
</svg>
```

However, append() is intended for a single element. If you have many elements, instead you could use `selection.each()` to add each selected element to a parent `g`:

```js
let svg = d3.select('svg')
let path = svg.selectAll('path').remove();
let g = svg.append('g');

path.each(function() {
  g.append(()=>this);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <path d="M 30 30 C 60 30 50 50 80 50" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none"></path>
  <path d="M 30 130 C 60 130 50 150 80 150" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none"></path>
</svg>
```

*The use of function() and fat arrow notation is intended to ensure the correct `this`, which is the element we want to add to the parent g*

This second snippet will work regardless of whether one or more nodes are selected.

Comment: There you go: https://jsbench.me/anl8vmcrl3/3

Comment: I made the erroneous assumption that the HTML woud be reset to its intial state for each execution of the test cases which is not the case. Hence, the DOM grows with each step in the loops getting bloated with more and more elements. This, of course, renders all tests invalid. I, then, thought I could clean up the DOM in the *setup* or *teardown* sections which also turned out to be a wrong assumption. Those scripts are run before/after each test case, i.e. before/after each loop, **not** before/after each single step of those loops!

Comment: I decided to make a call to a global cleanup function right after each execution of a test case which of course adds some bias but, at least, it adds the same bias to all test cases.

Comment: One thing to take away from this is that the spread syntax adds some seríous performance penalties to the execution as can be seen from the last, plain JS test that outperforms all other tests.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had thought there might be a penalty for using spread syntax, but thought it would be fairly negligible.

Answer (score 1):

In the past years I laid out some approaches similar to the [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73954288) proposed by Andrew Reid in his answer: [*"Can I move an SVG element between SVG groups, in d3.js"*](/a/60563243) and [*"D3.js how to embed selection into a new element"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32200469). However, digging deeper into this issue, I found a solution that uses VanillaJS DOM methods and does the whole shebang in a single method call.

The API of an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) knows some methods for adding multiple elements to the DOM at the same time. The [`element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) method can be used to elegantly and easily append your `path` elements to the new group in a single run.

```js
const path = d3.selectAll("path");

d3.select("svg")
  .insert("g")        // insert the new g at the first position
    .node()           // get the DOM node
    .append(          // use the DOM's append, not the D3 one
      ...path.nodes() // add the nodes from the path selection
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>

<svg id="mySvg">
  <path></path>
  <path></path>
  <path></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: I read through the snippet too quick - thought you were using spread operator with selection.append() - thought I was going crazy as I checked to see if that was possible with selection.append in the current version before posting. Had contemplated the js only solution - but your hybrid answer with some d3 is much more clean than what I had in mind.